# What is Lightning Element in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

I have gone through definition of LightningElement but unable to understand it clearly.

Definition
LightningElement is a custom wrapper of the standard HTML element.It extends element to create a JavaScript class for a Lightning web component.

Answer (score 7):

Additionally to what you found online:

> LightningElement is the base class for Lightning web components, which
> allows us to use connectedCallback().

[Source](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-basics/create-lightning-web-components).

In other words it's a JavaScript class that allows you to leverage on it when you [extend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends) it. Once you extend it the methods from that class become immediately available to you. Such as `connectedCallback()`, `renderedCallback()`, `disconnectedCallback()`, `errorCallback(error, stack)`, etc.

Additionally it's necessary to extend this class to supply a JS controller for your lightning web component.

If I erase the extends part from `export default class App extends LightningElement {` I get the following error:

> TypeError: class App {} is not a valid component, or does not extends
> LightningElement from "lwc". You probably forgot to add the extend
> clause on the class declaration.

If we look at the stacktrace(I'm doing this in LWC Playground) we can see that this error comes from a file called `engine.js`. That file has over 6000 rows so it is beyond my ability to comprehend it but maybe somebody else who is more familiar can add up to my answer.