# Can I use wire adapter in classes that do not inherit from LightningElement?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, js, lightning-message-service

Is it possible to use `@wire` in classes that do not inherit from `LightningElement`?

**Example:**

```
 export default class A {

    @wire
    messageContext;

 }
```

**What I want to achieve:**
I want to create a **Mixin** that will encapsulate logic for subscribing and unsubscribing **Lightning Message Service** context.

Comment: why this shouldn't be possible? what have you tried to implement this so far?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use @wire in classes that do not inherit from
> LightningElement?

No. You can save/deploy the file, but it won't work. Dragging it onto a page (even without a HTML file) will throw the following error:

> class n{yourWiredFunction({data:e,error:t}){}} is not a valid component,
> or **does not extends LightningElement from "lwc"**. You probably forgot
> to add the extend clause on the class declaration.

And there's no way to export a wired function to share with other components.

You can see the [Lightning Web Components Engine/Compiler](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc) and specifically, see [wire](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/blob/master/packages/%40lwc/engine-core/src/framework/decorators/wire.ts) and [base-lightning-element](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/blob/master/packages/%40lwc/engine-core/src/framework/base-lightning-element.ts). Since wired modules seem tied to component creation, it makes sense it can't be used without extending [LightningElement](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/311640/what-is-lightning-element-in-lightning-web-component) which is a part of that and allows you to leverage the lifecycle methods (ex. `connectedCallback()`, `renderedCallback()`, etc).

---

However, your scenario (`messageContext`) has specific mentions for creating a service component under the [message-service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation):

> Methods
>
> createMessageContext()
>
> Returns a MessageContext object.
>
> Call this function in a service component that doesn't extend
> LightningElement. In a service component, you can’t use
> @wire(MessageContext) to create a MessageContext object

And, with more details, in a note at the bottom of [Subscribe and Unsubscribe from a Message Channel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel_subscribe)

> NOTE **If you create a service component that isn’t a LightningElement,
> you can’t use @wire(MessageContext) to create the MessageContext
> object. Instead, import createMessageContext() and
> releaseMessageContext() methods from lightning/messageService**. Use
> createMessageContext() to create the Context object and assign it to a
> field, like messageContext. Then, pass messageContext into the
> subscribe() method. The context isn’t automatically released for
> service components. Call releaseMessageContext(messageContext) to
> remove any subscriptions associated with your component’s message
> context

It seems, while the answer to your question is "no", a wire adapter might not be necessary for your use case and you can still create a service component that does not extend `LightningElement`.

Comment: Eh... I wanted to avoid using `super` in `connectedCallback` and `disconnectedCallback` in the subclass to manually run parent's methods that are responsible for subscribing and unsubscribing from a message channel. But as I can see, there is no other approach there.